# LIKE operator in LINQ to XML?

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

Is there any way to use LIKE operator in LINQ to XML? I did try Googling but it results for Like operator in Linq to SQL not XML.
If yes, please recommend some reference. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please show some code that demonstrates the problem. Show the LINQ query.

Comment: You mean `Contains`, `StartsWith`, and `EndsWith` don't work?

Comment: @lc. I mean if I have the thousand of user names stored in xml file and I want to find all the names containing "xxx" like we do in SQL, is there any way apert from StartsWith & EndsWith?

Comment: using .Contains solved the problem, thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ to XML is simply LINQ to Objects. LINQ to Objects means that you run .NET code over collections and you can use .NET code to do the filtering. In .NET we can use `String.Contains`, `String.StartsWith` and `String.EndsWith` to check whether a string is part of another string.

Comment: got it, String.contains will do. Thanks for your help.